Using T-SQL, how to retrieve last average net price by the last year sold?
I have a report that contains basic sales data for items sold in the month. I would like to compare the item's price in the report to the average net price from the last year the item sold.
Example: if item #007750 was sold in 2024, I would like to know the average net price it sold for in 2023; if it didn't sell in 2023, then the report should look at 2022 etc... until it finds a year it sold in.
Sample data:



Date
Order No.
Item No.
Qty.
Unit Price
Line Disc %
Line Amount




02/04/2022
SO1999
001178
4
161.00
30%
450.80


04/13/2022
SO2045
001178
6
161.00
0%
966.00


12/17/2022
SO2203
001178
1
117.60
0%
117.60


05/23/2024
SO2468
001178
4
176.00
30%
492.80



Expected results
The database doesn't have a net price field so that will need to be solved in T-SQL as well



Date
Order No.
Item No.
Qty.
Unit Price
Line Disc %
Line Amount
Net Price Avg.




02/04/2022
SO1999
001178
4
161.00
30%
450.80
130.43


04/13/2022
SO2045
001178
6
161.00
0%
966.00
130.43


12/17/2022
SO2203
001178
1
117.60
0%
117.60
130.43


05/23/2024
SO2468
001178
4
176.00
30%
492.80
130.43




The net price average is coming from the 3 sales in 2022. Net unit prices were 112.70, 161.00 and 117.60 for the 3 sales.
If there was a sale in 2023, the report would use that net price average, so needs to look at the last year that had at least 1 sale.

Sample code
I'm not sure where to start to retrieve the average net price. Maybe using a CTE in some way?
SELECT
    InvoiceDate,
    OrderNo,
    ItemNo,
    Qty,
    UnitPrice,
    LineDiscPct,
    LineAmt
FROM 
    SalesInvoiceLine


You can achieve what you want with a series of nested queries or CTEs (Common Table Expressions) that

Calculate the current year average as AVG(LineAmount/Qty) grouped by item and year. (See the note below.)
Access the prior year's average using the LAG() window function.
Use COALESCE() to fall back to the current-year average if no prior-year sales exist. (I am assuming this behavior based on your desired results.)
Join the results back with your original data.

NOTE: Your calculation of "net price average" is a bit unusual. Typically a sales average would be a weighted average that takes into account the number of units per sale. This would be calculated as SUM(LineAmount) / SUM(Qty) instead of AVG(LineAmount/Qty).
WITH CTE_Avg AS (
    SELECT
        D.ItemNo,
        YEAR(D.Date) Year,
        --ROUND(SUM(D.LineAmount) / SUM(D.Qty), 2) AS CurrentNetPriceAvg
        ROUND(AVG(D.LineAmount / D.Qty), 2) AS CurrentNetPriceAvg
    FROM Data D
    GROUP BY D.ItemNo, YEAR(D.Date)
),
CTE_PriorAvg AS (
    SELECT
        A.Year,
        A.ItemNo,
        COALESCE(
            LAG(A.CurrentNetPriceAvg) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ItemNo ORDER BY A.YEAR),
            A.CurrentNetPriceAvg -- Use current year if no prior sales
            ) AS PriorNetPriceAvg
    FROM CTE_Avg A
)
SELECT
    D.*,
    PA.PriorNetPriceAvg AS NetPriceAvg
FROM Data D
JOIN CTE_PriorAvg PA
    ON PA.ItemNo = D.ItemNo
    AND PA.Year = YEAR(D.Date)
ORDER BY D.ItemNo, D.Date;

Sample results (with some extra data):



Date
OrderNo
ItemNo
Qty
UnitPrice
LineDisc
LineAmount
NetPriceAvg




2022-02-04
SO1999
001178
4
161.00
0.3000
450.80
130.43


2022-04-13
SO2045
001178
6
161.00
0.0000
966.00
130.43


2022-12-17
SO2203
001178
1
117.60
0.0000
117.60
130.43


2024-05-23
SO2468
001178
4
176.00
0.3000
492.80
130.43


2020-01-01
S00001
009999
2
100.00
0.1000
180.00
90.00


2022-01-01
S00002
009999
3
120.00
0.2000
288.00
90.00


2024-01-01
S00003
009999
4
140.00
0.3000
392.00
96.00



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This was a great solution and worked for me first try, thank you!                                                    There is one other addition to this that I'm wondering how you would approach coding it as well. I want to add an "inflation factor" specific to the year that had the last year's sales. So for instance, if the last net price average came from 2022 then * 1.03, if 2023 then * 1.07 etc... for each year.  Is there a way to do this?

You would likely need a table that stores the Consumer Price Index (or equivalent inflation index for your locale) with one row per year. The CTE_PriorAvg would need to be updated to also include a PriorYear column (populated using LAG() and COALESCE() similar to PriorNetPriceAvg. Another CTE can then lookup current and prior inflation index values and calculate the inflation factor as the ratio between the two. The updated query would be something similar to this db<>fiddle. You can adjust the results as needed.

Another way of getting the "latest_year" is to use CROSS APPLY:
with avgdata(Date, OrderNo, ItemNo, Qty, UnitPrice, LineDiscPc, 
    DiscUnitPrice, LineAmount, year, avgDiscUnitPrice, rn) as (
    select Date, OrderNo, ItemNo, Qty, UnitPrice, LineDisc, 
        UnitPrice * (1-LineDisc) as DiscUnitPrice, LineAmount,
        year(date) as year,
        avg(UnitPrice * (1-LineDisc)) over(partition by ItemNo, year(date)) as avgDiscUnitPrice,
        row_number() over(partition by ItemNo, year(date) order by date) as rn
    from data
)
select d.Date, d.OrderNo, d.ItemNo, d.Qty, d.UnitPrice, d.DiscUnitPrice, d.LineDiscPc, d.LineAmount,
        d.last_year, d1.avgDiscUnitPrice 
from (
    select d.Date, d.OrderNo, d.ItemNo, d.Qty, d.UnitPrice, d.DiscUnitPrice, d.LineDiscPc, d.LineAmount,
        coalesce(last_year, year) as last_year, 
        d.avgDiscUnitPrice
    from avgdata d
    cross apply (
        select max(year(d1.date)) as last_year from data d1 
            where d1.ItemNo = d.ItemNo and year(d1.date) < year(d.date)
    ) d1
) d
join avgdata d1 on d1.year = d.last_year and d1.rn = 1 and d.ItemNo = d1.ItemNo
order by d.date
;

https://dbfiddle.uk/uAqzIruZ
